# qsort reversing the order of string

Tags: c, arrays, string, qsort

I'm trying to use `qsort` to sort a string of characters alphabetically. At the moment it just seems to be reversing the order of my string.

```
printf("unsorted %s\n", string);
qsort(string, strlen(string), sizeof(char), compare);
printf("sorted %s\n", string);
```

string is the string "ACBD". The second printf shows it as "DBCA". My comparison function is,

```
compare(const void *a1, const void *b1){
     const int *a2 = a1;
     const int *b2 = b1;

     if(*a2 == *b2){
         return 0;
     }
     else{
         if(*a2 < *b2){
             return -1;
         }
         else{
             return 1;
         }
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing something pretty stupid but any help is appreciated.

Edit: string is declared as `char string[1000]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to do a character comparison but are actually doing an integer comparison (sizeof int > sizeof char).

Fix it as follows:

```
 char *a2 = a1;
 char *b2 = b1;
```

Comment: @user2655377 FYI you might be better off defining the comparison function as `int cmp(const void *a1, const void *b1) { return *(char *)a1 - *(char *)b1; }`

Comment: Consider actually dereferencing the pointers directly, too: `const char c1 = *(const char *) a1, c2 = *(const char *) b1;`, that makes the rest of the code simpler. As always, the comparison can be simplified to `return (c1 < c2) ? -1 : c1 > c2;`.

Comment: @Nirk That's not a very good idea, due to issues with arithmetic underflow the subtraction is not safe. Remember that `char` can be either signed or unsigned.

Comment: @unwind your complaint is irrelevant in this case: since `char` is smaller than `int`, the arguments are promoted to int when taking the difference but will not be truncated since the return type is `int`.  If the function return type were `char`, then I'd agree.  (one reference: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)